# aggregate of the group columns along with the group in a table

Tags: reporting-services

I am very new to Microsoft reporting. I have the following table in my database:

```
CategoryName    Id

Normal      1
High        2
Normal      3
Low           4
Normal      5
Normal      6
Normal      7
Normal      8
Low             9
Low             10
Low             11
High    12
```

I want to group by Category and also show the count of each category. Here is what I did:

I inserted a two column table and I grouped by the categoryName in the first column and in the second column, I tried doing

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!CategoryName.Value)
```

This is what I am seeing in the report

```
High   1
       1
Normal 1
       1
       1
       1
       1
       1
       1
Low    1
       1
       1
       1
```

I want to see something like this:

```
 Category   Count

    Normal  6
    Low     4
    High    2
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the Detail row and put the Count epxression in the Group row.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off doing this in the query. Easier and leaves less room for error.  Something like the following should work.

```
SELECT categoryName, COUNT(*)
FROM your table
GROUP BY categoryName
```